# Use different DataContext depending on user selection (inject datacontext)

Tags: c#, linq

I've made an app in MVC 4 to get reports using a javascript charting library, fancy LINQ statements (groupBys, select, etc.) and JSON (to feed chart data source). Everything is working excellent, performance is great and there's nothing but blue skies... BUT...

The system/app it's being deployed in different countries/locations with different sites and databases. The thing is that my customer needs to get the reports from all, some or one of those locations. Let's suppose that the systems are deployed in LA, NY and TX. The vicepresident needs to get reports and chooses in a dropdown list (or whatever...) to get data from NY and TX. Later, he just needs data from LA, and so on...

All DBs are inside one local network so i'm using LINQ Classes for the different data contexts. All context (and models) are exactly the same (so later on i can make Unions or whatever i want) and are under my absolute control.

My question is how do i approach this, overloading context to some controller/method but how can i do that? I've been looking for a while and can't get a solution or something to get in track.

What i think is something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetData(string? location){
    switch(location){
        case "NY":
            var data = GetMeReportData("NY"); //The idea is that NY calls the NY DataContext inside this method
            break;
        case "LA":
            var data = GetMetReportData("TX"); //And so on...
            break;
    }

}
```

The "example" above it's just to illustrate what i'm trying to do...

Waiting for your replies & suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to leverage a factory pattern.

The following example is of a rudimentary implementation of the concept.

```
public static MyContext CreateContext(string location)
    {
        MyContext result = null;
        string databaseName = string.Empty;
        switch(location)
        {
           case "NY":
              databaseName = "NyDb";
              break;
          case "LA":
              databaseName = "LaDb";
              break;
        }


        var connectionName = "Name=" + databaseName;

        result = new MyContext(connectionName);
        return result;
    }
```